# onCreate method keeps getting called when the orientation of device changes

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask, screen-orientation, oncreate

I have an `AsyncTask` which gets called `onCreate()` in my `Main Activity`. In the same `Activity` if the orientation changes the `AsyncTask` gets called again. How do I prevent this from happening or how do I restructure my program to avoid this happening?

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pages);
        StartProcess sProcess = new StartProcess();
        sProcess.execute(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Will forbidding your application from changing orientation solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `android:configChanges="orientation"` in the Activity manifest and manually set the contentView or change the layout by overriding the [onConfigurationChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29) method in your Activity.

Answer (score 3):

You should check [Handling Run Time Changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)

You can Handle either by using

**Retain an object during a configuration change**

*Allow your activity to restart when a configuration changes, but carry a stateful Object to the new instance of your activity.*

**Handle the configuration change yourself**

*Prevent the system from restarting your activity during certain configuration changes, but receive a callback when the configurations do change, so that you can manually update your activity as necessary.*

To retain an object during a runtime configuration change:

Override the **onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() method** to return the object you would like to retain.

When your activity is created again, call **getLastNonConfigurationInstance()** to recover your object.

```
@Override
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
    final MyDataObject data = collectMyLoadedData();
    return data;
}
```

Retain in OnCreate ;

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final MyDataObject data = (MyDataObject) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
    if (data == null) {
        data = loadMyData();
    }
    ...
}
```

Or simply add this code in you Manifest of you Activity

```
 android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

or

```
 android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```